# How to bind to the dependency property of the dependency object?

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

The following is only a summary of the core of the problem.

I defined the class that has one dependency property is as below.

```
public class TestMap : DependencyObject
{
    public bool TestProperty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(TestPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestProperty", typeof(bool), typeof(TestMap), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Now I'm going to use the above class in the UserControl.
The following code is an example.

```
public class UserControl1 : Control
{
    public TestMap TestMap { get; set; }
}
```

And I used the UserControl1 in the MainWindow like below.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above code works well but If I try to binding to the TestMap.TestProperty what I should do?
I tried the following code but it doesn't work. (Assume ViewModel is bound)

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 TestMap.TestProperty="{Binding ViewModelProperty}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The error message for the above code is as below image.

[image]

The error message is 
"It can't found connectable 'TestProperty' property in the 'TestMap' format."

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can't bind to nested properties like that in XAML. Perhaps you should consider using an [attached dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview).

Comment: Besides that the syntax is not supported, `TestMap` is obviously `null`, so there is no object where a Binding could be set. Any reason why `TestProperty` is not in `UserControl1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to a nested property, i.e. a property `TestProperty` of the object returned by the property `TestMap`, like this in XAML. It's not supported.

You should either move the `TestProperty` to the `UserControl`, set it programatically, or consider using an [attached dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) that is settable on any object of a specific type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.